# Displaying a div on specific position

Tags: html, css, web

I have created a `webpage`,which look like this [image]

I have to display a image gallery in the yellow mark which I have made. I haved tried everything but it comes below the `footer`. Can I get some idea how can I achieve this?

here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="pull-left">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="pull-right">
                    <li>Welcome to our Store</li>
                    <li><a href="login_page.html">Login</a></li>
                    <li>or</li>
                    <li><a href="register_page.html">Register</a></li>
                    <li>yourself!</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="extra0">
            <div class="cata-head">
                Choose a category!
            </div>
            <ul class="cata">

                <li><a href="#">Men's Clothing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Men's Accesories</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Women's Clothing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Women's Accesories</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Baby Products</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="extra">
            <a href="#"><img src="extra.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="extra1.png"></a>
        </div> 

        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm"><img src="p1.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis2_big.htm"><img src="klematis2_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis3_big.htm"><img src="klematis3_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis4_big.htm"><img src="klematis4_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>

        <div class="foot">
            <footer>
                Policies: Terms of use | Security | Privacy | Infringement &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <b> UsamaRehan & AsjadHussaini&#169;</style> </b>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="https://facebook.com"><img src="face.png"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="https://twitter.com"><img src="tweet.png"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="https://youtube.com"><img src="you.png"></a>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

******CSS

```
body {
     //overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #d0e4fe;
    //background-image: url("background.jpg");
    font-family: "Book Antiqua",Times New Roman, Georgia, Serif;


}
.nav
{
    border-style: solid;
}
.nav a {
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;

}

a:hover {
    color: coral;
}
.pull-left
{

    float:left
}

.pull-right
{
    float:right
}

.clear
{
    clear:both;
}
.container
{
    padding-right: 75px;

    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color:#bbb;
}

.extra0{

    background-color: #555;
    width: 250px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #0ca3d2;

}
.cata-head
{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 0px 5px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: activeborder;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #0ca3d2;

    border-left-color:#555;
    border-right-color: #555;
    border-top-color: #555;



}
.cata
{
    color: #b3c0c8;
    list-style-image: url("list.png");
    line-height: 2.333em;

}

.foot
{
    background:#ffab62;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;

}
b
{
    color: firebrick;
}
.extra
{
    width: 250px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
}

.main
{

   border-style: solid;
   border-color: black;
   display: block;
   width: 250px;
   margin: 10px 10px;

}
div.img {
   /* margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;*/
    margin: 10px 10px;
    width: auto;
    border:3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}

div.img img {
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

div.img a:hover img {
    border:1px solid #0000ff;
}

div.desc {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have add some new div and css here is link check : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BobQzo

```css
body {
     //overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #d0e4fe;
    //background-image: url("background.jpg");
    font-family: "Book Antiqua",Times New Roman, Georgia, Serif;


}
.nav
{
    border-style: solid;
}
.nav a {
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;

}

a:hover {
    color: coral;
}
.pull-left
{

    float:left
}

.sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}
.pull-right
{
    float:right
}

.clear
{
    clear:both;
}
.container
{
    padding-right: 75px;

    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color:#bbb;
}
.gallery {
    
    float: left;
 width:80%;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
    
}

.extra0{

    background-color: #555;
    width: 250px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #0ca3d2;

}
.cata-head
{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 0px 5px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: activeborder;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #0ca3d2;

    border-left-color:#555;
    border-right-color: #555;
    border-top-color: #555;



}
.cata
{
    color: #b3c0c8;
    list-style-image: url("list.png");
    line-height: 2.333em;

}

.foot
{
    background:#ffab62;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
 float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;

}
b
{
    color: firebrick;
}
.extra
{
    width: 250px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
}

.main
{

   border-style: solid;
   border-color: black;
   display: block;
   width: 250px;
   margin: 10px 10px;

}
div.img {
   /* margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;*/
    margin: 10px 10px;
    width: auto;
    border:3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}

div.img img {
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

div.img a:hover img {
    border:1px solid #0000ff;
}

div.desc {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="pull-left">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="pull-right">
                    <li>Welcome to our Store</li>
                    <li><a href="login_page.html">Login</a></li>
                    <li>or</li>
                    <li><a href="register_page.html">Register</a></li>
                    <li>yourself!</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="sidebar">
        <div class="extra0">
            <div class="cata-head">
                Choose a category!
            </div>
            <ul class="cata">

                <li><a href="#">Men's Clothing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Men's Accesories</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Women's Clothing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Women's Accesories</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Baby Products</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="extra">
            <a href="#"><img src="extra.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="extra1.png"></a>
        </div> 
</div>
<div class="gallery">
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm"><img src="p1.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
  <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm"><img src="p1.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
  <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm"><img src="p1.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
  <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm"><img src="p1.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
  <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm"><img src="p1.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
  <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm"><img src="p1.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
  <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm"><img src="p1.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
  <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm"><img src="p1.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis2_big.htm"><img src="klematis2_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis3_big.htm"><img src="klematis3_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis4_big.htm"><img src="klematis4_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
</div>
        <div class="foot">
            <footer>
                Policies: Terms of use | Security | Privacy | Infringement &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <b> UsamaRehan & AsjadHussaini&#169;</style> </b>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="https://facebook.com"><img src="face.png"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="https://twitter.com"><img src="tweet.png"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="https://youtube.com"><img src="you.png"></a>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

there is two div one sidebar and gallery

Answer (score 1):

I have added some extra div to float the element. here is the link below http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYwVLM

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="pull-left">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="pull-right">
                    <li>Welcome to our Store</li>
                    <li><a href="login_page.html">Login</a></li>
                    <li>or</li>
                    <li><a href="register_page.html">Register</a></li>
                    <li>yourself!</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="pull-left">
        <div class="extra0">
            <div class="cata-head">
                Choose a category!
            </div>
            <ul class="cata">

                <li><a href="#">Men's Clothing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Men's Accesories</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Women's Clothing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Women's Accesories</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Baby Products</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="extra">
            <a href="#"><img src="extra.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="extra1.png"></a>
        </div> 
</div>
<div class="pull-left">
  ADD GALLERY HERE <br>
       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200">

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
       <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm"><img src="p1.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis2_big.htm"><img src="klematis2_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis3_big.htm"><img src="klematis3_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis4_big.htm"><img src="klematis4_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>

<div class="clear"></div>

        <div class="foot">
            <footer>
                Policies: Terms of use | Security | Privacy | Infringement &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <b> UsamaRehan & AsjadHussaini&#169;</style> </b>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="https://facebook.com"><img src="face.png"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="https://twitter.com"><img src="tweet.png"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="https://youtube.com"><img src="you.png"></a>
            </footer>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
    body {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #d0e4fe;
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
    font-family: "Book Antiqua",Times New Roman, Georgia, Serif;


}

.nav
{
    border-style: solid;
}
.nav a {
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;

}

a:hover {
    color: coral;
}
.pull-left
{

    float:left;
}

.pull-right
{
    float:right;
}

.clear
{
    clear:both;
}
.container
{
    padding-right: 75px;

    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color:#bbb;
}

.extra0{

    background-color: #555;
    width: 250px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #0ca3d2;

}
.cata-head
{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 0px 5px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: activeborder;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #0ca3d2;

    border-left-color:#555;
    border-right-color: #555;
    border-top-color: #555;



}
.cata
{
    color: #b3c0c8;
    list-style-image: url("list.png");
    line-height: 2.333em;

}

.foot
{
    background:#ffab62;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;

}
b
{
    color: firebrick;
}
.extra
{
    width: 250px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
}

.main
{

   border-style: solid;
   border-color: black;
   display: block;
   width: 250px;
   margin: 10px 10px;

}
div.img {
   /* margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;*/
    margin: 10px 10px;
    width: auto;
    border:3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}

div.img img {
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

div.img a:hover img {
    border:1px solid #0000ff;
}

div.desc {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i changed you html structure i.e

Created one div with class gallery and  put all images inside that div

in your html your images doesn't have any parent. if you use parent then it will help to move all chilled according to parent.

**Note : see result in full screen**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="extra0">
     </div>
    <div class="gallery">
    <!---all imaged-->
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
    //overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #d0e4fe;
    //background-image: url("background.jpg");
    font- amily: "Book Antiqua", Times New Roman, Georgia, Serif;
}

.nav {
    border - style: solid;
}

.nav a {
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
}

a:hover {
    color: coral;
}

.pull-left {
    float: left
}

.pull-right {
    float: right
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.container {
    padding-right: 75px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: # bbb;
    width: 100 %;
    display: inline-block;
}

.extra0 {
    background-color: #555;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #0ca3d2;
}

.cata - head {
    font-size: 18 px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 0px 5px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: activeborder;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #0ca3d2;
    border-left-color: #555;
    border-right-color: #555;
    border-top-color: #555;
}

.cata {
    color: #b3c0c8;
    list-style - image: url("list.png");
    line-height: 2.333em;
}

.foot {
    background: #ffab62;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

b {
    color: firebrick;
}

.extra {
    width: 250px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
}

.main {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
}

div.img {
    /* margin: 5px;
     padding: 5px;
     border: 1px solid #0000ff;
     height: auto;
     width: auto;
     float: left;
     text-align: center;*/
    margin: 10px 10px;
    width: auto;
    border: 3 px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}

div.img img {
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

div.img a: hover img {
    border: 1 px solid #0000ff;
}

div.desc {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.gallery {
    width: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="pull-left">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="pull-right">
            <li>Welcome to our Store</li>
            <li><a href="login_page.html">Login</a></li>
            <li>or</li>
            <li><a href="register_page.html">Register</a></li>
            <li>yourself!</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="extra0">
        <div class="cata-head">
            Choose a category!
        </div>
        <ul class="cata">
            <li><a href="#">Men's Clothing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Men's Accesories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Women's Clothing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Women's Accesories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Baby Products</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm"><img src="p1.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis2_big.htm"><img src="klematis2_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis3_big.htm"><img src="klematis3_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="klematis4_big.htm"><img src="klematis4_small.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90"></a>
            <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="extra">
    <a href="#"><img src="extra.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="extra1.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="foot">
    <footer>
        Policies: Terms of use | Security | Privacy | Infringement &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <b> UsamaRehan & AsjadHussaini&#169;</style> </b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="https://facebook.com"><img src="face.png"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="https://twitter.com"><img src="tweet.png"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="https://youtube.com"><img src="you.png"></a>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think you can use position absolute and give the top & left for your div.**
    .img{
            position: absolute;
            top: 30px;
            left: 30px;
        }